# Get actual data (array) from nodejs buffer

Tags: node.js, buffer

I have a node js buffer object returned by certain function. That object should be created with array of integers. How can retrieve actual data (array of integers in my case) contained by node buffer in javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UintXArray` constructors, but you have to know the size of the integers and whether you're working in BE or LE.

If you have an array of 32 bit integers already in LE called `b` you can do

```
const intArr = Uint32Array.from(b)
```

If it's in BE you need to swap it

```
b.swap32();
const intArr = Uint32Array.from(b)
```

Buffer related functions are sensitive to node version, check the [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/buffer.html)

Typed arrays aren't in the node docs, but you can find them at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray)